# replica set unable to add a node

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to create a replica set. I had create a primary node then I am trying to add a secondary node but it gives an error message

> Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responde                                            d; required 2 but only the following 1 voting nodes responded:...

Anyone know what the problems is?

Comment: This can be any one of these: 1.[Adding a replica in MongoDB throws an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480021/adding-a-replica-in-mongodb-throws-an-error)  2. [Can't config replica set using MongoDB 3](https://serverfault.com/questions/707006/cant-config-replica-set-using-mongodb-3) 3. [Having trouble initializing a replica set](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/DGP6Ak4dq4k)

Comment: Please post the output of `rs.conf()`

Comment: And `rs.Status()` would not hurt, either

Answer (score 1):

Simple. It means that your node cannot connect that other node. Check firewall settings between those nodes.

If you go to the command line, `telnet node.ip.addr.ess 27107` should work.